# How do I get synergy to work?

Tags: synergy

I've never actually been able to get Synergy working, even when using QuickSynergy. Even using [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynergyHowto) gives me nothing; my mouse won't leave the edge of my screen. I've even disabled both computers' `ufw` firewalls to make sure ports aren't being blocked. What am I doing wrong?

work-macbook, host computer:

```
[Share]
Left=work-laptop

[Use]
Hostname=
ClientName=

[Settings]
SynergyPath=/usr/bin
```

work-laptop, slave computer:

```
[Use]
Hostname=work-macbook
ClientName=work-macbook

[Settings]
SynergyPath=/usr/bin
```

Pinging work-macbook from work-laptop works, and pinging work-laptop from work-macbook works. Things are basically working with host-names to IP addresses on my network, so that doesn't seem like the issue:

Pings:

```
work-macbook $ ping work-laptop
64 bytes from work-laptop (192.168.1.2)

work-laptop $ ping work-macbook
64 bytes from work-macbook (192.168.1.49)
```

Comment: Done, sorry about that.

Comment: Have you tried using the IP addresses in the config file for hostname and clientname?

Comment: @Kendor Yes I have. Really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting up your config file on the host as shown in the [synergy docs](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html)?

Name the text file ".synergy.conf" in your host home folder.

Something like this:

```
section: screens
    work-macbook:
    work-laptop:
end

section: links
    work-macbook:
        left =      work-laptop
    work-laptop:
        right =     work-macbook
end
```

Then run "synergys" on the host and I believe it's "synergyc -a [address]" on the client.
You can run synergyc with the -f option to make it run in the foreground, that might tell you something about why it's not working.

Comment: Evidently, there _was_ a DNS issue, but this conf fixed it and things are working GREAT now. Thanks! I had to run `synergyc IPADDRESS`

Answer (score 0):

To me, in Ubuntu, running `synergyc [Server-IP-address]` works.

It invokes synergy client daemon with the argument of IP address of the server. When I get problem with synergy on my Ubuntu (client), I just kill the daemon and re-run by this command.

Comment: Can you explain what this command does?

Comment: Its invokes synergy client daemon with the argument of IP address of server. When I got problem with synergy on my ubuntu(client), I just kill the daemon and re-run by this command

Comment: Add that information to your answer so people know more about it. I asked this because your answer is considerably short, and posting commands without explaining them is looked down upon (security reasons, etc).

Comment: Its a good advice, will notice for the next time!